# Out of memory error when loading bitmap from Uri

Tags: android, bitmap

I am using the following method to get the `Bitmap` from a `Uri` :

```
private static Bitmap getBitmapFromUri(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull Uri uri) throws IOException {

        ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor =
                context.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
        assert parcelFileDescriptor != null;
        FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = parcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor();
        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor);
        parcelFileDescriptor.close();
        return image;
    }
```

The problem is, I am sometimes getting OOM errors in the return statement from `Crashlytics`. I assume it is happening because the selected image is of a large size. How do modify it so as to return the best quality scaled down version of Bitmap so that it does not cause Out of memory error?

**Edit** I have posted an answer myself. Please have a look and let me know it is the correct way to do it.

Comment: post the decodeFileDescriptor() method also.

Comment: down sample your image. Checkout this link http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: @saurabhgupta I have not written that function. It is built-in. I found this method in Android docs itself. I just need to modify it to get the best scaled down version of bitmap if it is going to give an OOM error.

Comment: @AmitTiwari...see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read all the answers and this is what I am planning to do, tell me if it will work or not. In my `Application` class, in `onCreate()`, I store the device width and height in pixels in the `SharedPreferences`. In the modified code, I scale the bitmap according to the device pixels. Hope it will spare me the OOM error.

```
private static Bitmap getBitmapFromUri(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull Uri uri) throws IOException {

        ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor =
                context.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
        assert parcelFileDescriptor != null;
        FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = parcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor();
        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor);
        parcelFileDescriptor.close();

        TinyDB tinyDB = new TinyDB(context);
        int maxSize = Math.min(tinyDB.getInt(AppConstants.DEVICE_WIDTH, 720), tinyDB.getInt(AppConstants.DEVICE_HEIGHT, 1080));
        int outWidth;
        int outHeight;
        int inWidth = image.getWidth();
        int inHeight = image.getHeight();
        if(inWidth > inHeight){
            outWidth = maxSize;
            outHeight = (inHeight * maxSize) / inWidth;
        } else {
            outHeight = maxSize;
            outWidth = (inWidth * maxSize) / inHeight;
        }

        return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, outWidth, outHeight, false);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to resize your image before decode. Here is my code to decode an image and display it in an image view.

```
private void loadImage(Uri u, String path) {
    try {
        ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
        InputStream in;
        in = cr.openInputStream(u);
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, o);
        in.close();

        int scale = 1;
        if (o.outHeight > IMAGE_MAX_SIZE || o.outWidth > IMAGE_MAX_SIZE) {
            scale = (int) Math.pow(2, (int) Math.round(Math.log(IMAGE_MAX_SIZE / (double) Math.max(o.outHeight, o.outWidth)) / Math.log(0.5)));
        }

        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        in = cr.openInputStream(u);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, o2);
        in.close();
        Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), getRotation(path), true);

        int nh = (int) ( rotatedBitmap.getHeight() * (512.0 / rotatedBitmap.getWidth()) );
        Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(rotatedBitmap, 512, nh, true);
        String pathTest = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(context.getContentResolver(), scaled, "Title", null);
        ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        imageLoader.displayImage(Uri.decode(Uri.parse(pathTest).toString()), mPicture, new ImageLoadingListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                mPicture.setImageBitmap(loadedImage);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view) {

            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //Toast.makeText(context, context.getString(R.string.fail_to_load_image), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.e("TAG", e.toString());
    }
}

private Matrix getRotation(String pathPetPicture) {
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    try {
        ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(pathPetPicture);
        int rotation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);

        switch (rotation) {
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_FLIP_HORIZONTAL:
                matrix.setScale(-1, 1);
                break;

            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                matrix.setRotate(180);
                break;

            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_FLIP_VERTICAL:
                matrix.setRotate(180);
                matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
                break;

            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_TRANSPOSE:
                matrix.setRotate(90);
                matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
                break;

            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                matrix.setRotate(90);
                break;

            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_TRANSVERSE:
                matrix.setRotate(-90);
                matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
                break;

            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                matrix.setRotate(-90);
                break;

            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:
            default:
                break;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("TAG", e.toString());
    }

    return matrix;
}
```

Comment: How do you determine the IMAGE_MAX_SIZE ?

Comment: Generally it corresponds to the height of the image view to keep ratio of your image. And your image view must have the attribute scale type center crop.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this...

```
 // decode image
        public Bitmap decodeFile(String filePath) {
            // Decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, o);
            // The new size we want to scale to
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 1024;
            // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
            int scale = 1;
            while (true) {
                if (width_tmp < REQUIRED_SIZE && height_tmp < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break;
                width_tmp /= 2;
                height_tmp /= 2;
                scale *= 2;
            }

            // Decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, o2);            
            return bitmap;
        }
```

May it help.

and if you want Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently then follow [this](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)

Comment: Your solution is fine. But I just don't want to hardcode the REQUIRED_SIZE. I want it to be dynamically determined. Is there a way to do that? Because the REQUIRED_SIZE might not give OOM on a high-end phone but it may give OOM on a low-end phone.

Answer (score 1):

```
Bitmap bm;
bm = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filepath), 100, 100,     true);
mPicture = new ImageView(context);
mPicture.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

Use this and replace your code with this in getBitmapFromUri()

Comment: I don't want to hardcode any value like 100. I want it to be of best quality such that it won't overflow the memory. How can I do that?

Comment: is this image coming from URL , if so don't create bitmap just use Picasso to show it will not re size it

Comment: I know. But the image is being loaded from phone's gallery.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) or [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso) libraries:

Replace path with local folder path or server url

```
Glide.with (context).load (path).asBitmap().into(imageView);
```